# React Native Animated lagging - Prevent Re-Rendering by function call

Tags: react-native

**Context**

Im want to get a countdown value which I then want to pass as prop to a separate component animating a progress bar. the data.json contains two type of elements:

- text
- question

the text will present the user an explanation. when the user pushes the button another text can be shown or a question. when it is a question the user will have certain amount of time for the answer. the progress bar will indicate the remaining time and shall only be shown when the current element is a question.

**Problem**

My problem is that the screen update for the current value is super slow and I can't see the reason. here is a simplified version of my code. the progress bar component will replace the `<Text>{this.state.value}</Text>` within the `renderButtons` function

**Versions**

I am running react native 0.60.

**Update 1**

I found out that when I trigger the `countdown` function by an `onPress` event, it works. but if I call it directly it doesn't. Why is that? How could I achieve it without the `onPress`

**Update 2**

the problem is that due to the animation the state value gets updated an by that a serenader gets triggered, which causes the function to be called each time, which is causing the lagging. this workaround seems to help but it feels ugly.

what would be a better approach to handle the re-rendering issue?

```
countdown = type => {
    if (!this.state.countdownRunning) {
      this.setState({ countdownRunning: true });
      if (type === 'question') {
        this.state.percent.addListener(({ value }) => this.setState({ value }));

        Animated.timing(
          // Animate value over time
          this.state.percent, // The value to drive
          {
            toValue: 0, // Animate to final value of 1
            duration: 25000,
            easing: Easing.linear
          }
        ).start(() => {
          console.log('Animation DONE');
          this.setState({ value: 100, percent: new Animated.Value(100) });
          this.onPressNext();
          this.setState({ countdownRunning: false });
        }); // Start the animation
      }
    }
  };
```

**Lagging**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import Card from '../components/Card';
import data from '../data/data.json';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5
  },
  surface: {
    padding: 20,
    margin: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    elevation: 12
  }
});

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.countdown = this.countdown.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      i: 0,
      questions: data,
      value: 100,
      percent: new Animated.Value(100)
    };
  }

  onPressNext = () => {
    const { i } = this.state;

    if (i < 17) {
      this.setState({ i: i + 1 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ i: 0 });
    }
  };

  onPressBack = () => {
    const { i } = this.state;

    if (i > 0) {
      this.setState({ i: i - 1 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ i: 17 });
    }
  };

  countdown = type => {
    if (type === 'question') {
      this.state.percent.addListener(({ value }) => this.setState({ value }));

      Animated.timing(
        // Animate value over time
        this.state.percent, // The value to drive
        {
          toValue: 0, // Animate to final value of 1
          duration: 25000,
          easing: Easing.linear
        }
      ).start(); // Start the animation
    }
  };

  renderButtons = type => {
    if (type === 'question') {
      this.countdown(type);
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Button mode="text" onPress={() => this.onPressBack()}>
          Zurück
        </Button>
        <Button mode="contained" onPress={() => this.onPressNext(type)}>
          Weiter
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { i, questions } = this.state;
    const { type, header, content } = questions.data[i.toString()];

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 2, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
          <Card>
            <Text>{header}</Text>
            <Text>{content}</Text>
          </Card>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>{this.renderButtons(type)}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**No Lagging**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import Card from '../components/Card';
import data from '../data/data.json';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5
  },
  surface: {
    padding: 20,
    margin: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    elevation: 12
  }
});

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.countdown = this.countdown.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      i: 0,
      questions: data,
      value: 100,
      percent: new Animated.Value(100)
    };
  }

  onPressNext = () => {
    const { i } = this.state;

    if (i < 17) {
      this.setState({ i: i + 1 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ i: 0 });
    }
  };

  onPressBack = () => {
    const { i } = this.state;

    if (i > 0) {
      this.setState({ i: i - 1 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ i: 17 });
    }
  };

  countdown = type => {
    if (type === 'question') {
      this.state.percent.addListener(({ value }) => this.setState({ value }));

      Animated.timing(
        // Animate value over time
        this.state.percent, // The value to drive
        {
          toValue: 0, // Animate to final value of 1
          duration: 25000,
          easing: Easing.linear
        }
      ).start(); // Start the animation
    }
  };

  renderButtons = type => {
    if (type === 'question') {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.value}</Text>
          <Button mode="contained" onPress={() => this.countdown(type)}>
            Weiter
          </Button>
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Button mode="text" onPress={() => this.onPressBack()}>
          Zurück
        </Button>
        <Button mode="contained" onPress={() => this.onPressNext(type)}>
          Weiter
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { i, questions } = this.state;
    const { type, header, content } = questions.data[i.toString()];

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 2, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
          <Card>
            <Text>{header}</Text>
            <Text>{content}</Text>
          </Card>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>{this.renderButtons(type)}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: You can use `react-redux`

Comment: what diference would that make? as I just want change the value?

Comment: You can prevent slow change by using the reductus.

Comment: I posted an update. I found out that it works when I call the countdown() function by an onPress Event. What is the difference to calling it directly?